# Power Automate flow to permanently delete SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have been able to use a POST request to the API '_api/SPSiteManager/delete' to soft delete a SharePoint site. But I am looking for a method to permanently delete sites. Currently the sites are in the 'Deleted Sites' in the SharePoint admin centre, but I am looking for a method to delete them from here using Power Automate, or else skip them going in there and being permanently deleted immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, we only could delete a site by using flow but could not delete a site from Deleted sites in the Central Administration.

Example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1359241/how-to-delete-non-group-connected-sharepoint-sites